# No aparece el android:label en mis Activities de mi app en Android Studio 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Tags: android-studio

1.Aquí es el label de mi aplicación, ya que tengo dos activites
 `android:label="@string/app_name"`

2.este es mi primer activity, con el label de Agregar datos:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Agregar datos"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2.Al correr la aplicación sí funciona todo correctamente, pero no me aparecen los labels, ya hice de todo para arreglarlo, pero nada más no jala